# How to add a money sign in front of my input field in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an input field which I want a dollar sign to the left. I checked the docs and I tried to do it with `InputAdornment` but every time I did it, the dollar sign would never show up. Here's my code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wnei9?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of start adornment use the below code in the `Input` field.

```
InputProps={{
  startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>,
}}
```

Comment: This is correct. The question remains why this is required.

Comment: I would like to know this as well

Comment: @Mordechai and @A.K.M. Adib yes as @userhooke said,  this is the syntax for `textfield` which you imported. To follow the docs, you have to import the `input` from material-ui

Comment: @A.K.M.Adib I see!! You imported `TextField` as `Input`, not `Input` directly....

Answer (score 2):

You just imported the wrong `Input`.

In `demo.js` on line 5: `import Input from "@material-ui/core/TextField";`

The correct import would be: `import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';`

Answer (score 1):

Please change the 'value' attribute like this to get the symbol before the input.

```
    <Input
      className={classes.input}
      value={"$" + value}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">A</InputAdornment>}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them with Grid.

Change your code with this:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 250
  },
  input: {
    width: 100
  }
});

export default function InputSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(500);

  const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value === "" ? "" : Number(event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Slider
        min={500}
        max={10000}
        value={typeof value === "number" ? value : 0}
        onChange={handleSliderChange}
        aria-labelledby="input-slider"
      />

      <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin}>
        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
          <Grid item>$</Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Input
              className={classes.input}
              value={value}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              startAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="start">A</InputAdornment>
              }
              style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```